# Tablesorter do not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, tablesorter

I'm doing a web portal and I want to sort a table without refresh the page. When I try it with a static table it works perfect but when I do with my table that it uses information from the database it doesn't work...

This is my code, I spent almost all day searching the problem but I feel unable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" href="img/favicon.jpg" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Purchase Orders</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/ordonez.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/master.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/datepicker.css" /> <!-- Estilos calendario -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //cuando la página se cargue convertimos la tabla con id "tabla_ordenada" en una tabla ordenable
            $("#tabla_ordenada").tablesorter();

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
     <?php
        include("../fragmentos/cookies.php");
        require("../fragmentos/es/menu.php");
    ?>
    <div class="container ordonez min">
        <?php
            require_once ('../fragmentos/swap_lang.php');
            require_once ('../fragmentos/funciones.php');
            require_once ('../fragmentos/conexion_bbdd.php');
            error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
        ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-right">
                <a href="panel.php" class="margen_arriba btn btn-orange hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm" id="">
                    Claims register
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
                <h4 class="">Filtros de búsqueda:</h4>
                <form action="orders.php" method="post">
                    <div class="caja_gris margen_arriba">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Estado</label>
                                            <div class="styled-select">
                                                <select name="status" class="form-control">
                                                    <option <?php if(!isset($_POST["status"])){echo ' selected';}?> value="0">---Sin definir---</option>
                                            <?php
                                                $sql = "select * from estado_envio order by estado ASC";
                                                $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
                                                while($estado = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
                                            ?>
                                                    <option <?php if($_POST["status"]==$estado["id"]){ echo ' selected';} echo ' value="'.$estado["id"].'">'; echo $estado["estado"].'</option>';} ?>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>                                
                                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Nombre Proveedor</label>
                                            <div class="styled-select">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" <?php if(isset($_POST["name"])){echo ' value="'.$_POST["name"].'"';}?>>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Punto Descarga</label>
                                                <div class="styled-select">
                                                    <select name="punto_descarga" class="form-control">
                                                        <option <?php if(!isset($_POST["punto_descarga"])){echo ' selected';}?> value="0">---Sin definir---</option>
                                                    <?php
                                                        print_r($_POST);
                                                        $sql = "select * from discharge_point order by nombre";
                                                        $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
                                                        while($punto = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
                                                    ?>
                                                        <option <?php if($_POST["punto_descarga"]==$punto["id"]){ echo ' selected';} echo ' value="'.$punto["id"].'">'; echo $punto["nombre"].'</option>';} ?>                                                      
                                                    </select>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Orden Ordoñez</label>
                                            <div class="styled-select">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="orden_ordonez" <?php if(isset($_POST["orden_ordonez"])){echo ' value="'.$_POST["orden_ordonez"].'"';}?>>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Artículo Proveedor</label>
                                            <div class="styled-select">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="art_proveedor" <?php if(isset($_POST["art_proveedor"])){echo ' value="'.$_POST["art_proveedor"].'"';}?>>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Fecha Entrega Confirmada</label>
                                            <div class="styled-select has-feedback">
                                                <input data-provide="datepicker" class="form-control datepicker"  name="confirm_fecha_ent"<?php if(isset($_POST["confirm_fecha_ent"])){echo ' value="'.$_POST["confirm_fecha_ent"].'"';}?> >
                                                <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar form-control-feedback"></span> 
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pull-right margen_arriba_extra margen_derecha">
                                        <input class="btn btn-orange" type="submit" name="submit">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="resultados" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
                <h4 class="">Órdenes:</h4>
                <div id="tabla_1" class="table-responsive">
                    <table id="tabla_ordenada" class="table tabla_gris">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="text-center">Estado</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Nombre Proveedor</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Punto Descarga</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Orden Ordoñez</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Artículo Proveedor</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Fecha Entrega Confirmada</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php
                                $cont = 0;
                                $where = getSearchOrderConditions($_POST);
                                $sql = "select * from purchase_order".$where;
                                $sql2 = "select * from discharge_point";
                                $sql3 = "select * from estado_envio_en";
                                if($resultado = $mysqli->query($sql)){
                                    while($orders = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
                                        if($cont%2==1){
                                            echo '<tr class="fila_gris">';
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            echo '<tr>';
                                        }
                                        $cont++;
                                        $sql2 = "select * from estado_envio where id = '".$orders["estado"]."'";
                                        $resultado2 = $mysqli->query($sql2);
                                        $estado = $resultado2->fetch_assoc();
                                        echo '<td class="text-center"><span class="al">'.$estado["estado"].'</span></td>';
                                        echo '<td class="text-center"><span class="al">'.$orders["nombre_proveedor"].'</span></td>';
                                        $sql2 = "select * from discharge_point where id = '".$orders["punto_descarga"]."'";
                                        $resultado2 = $mysqli->query($sql2);
                                        $discharge_point = $resultado2->fetch_assoc();
                                        echo '<td class="text-center"><span class="al">'.$discharge_point["nombre"].'</span></td>';
                                        echo '<td class="text-center"><span class="al">'.$orders["orden_ordonez"].'</span></td>';
                                        echo '<td class="text-center"><span class="al">'.$orders["art_proveedor"].'</span></td>';
                                        echo '<td class="text-center"><span class="al">'.$orders["confirm_fecha_ent"].'</span></td>';       
                                        echo '</tr>';
                                    }
                                }
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="44">
                                    <table width="100%" class="tabla_sin_borde">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>

                                                <td class="text-center">
                                                    <nav class="pull-right margen_derecha">
                                                        <ul class="pagination pull-right">
                                                            <li class="pag_2">
                                                                <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                                                                    <span aria-hidden="true">«</span>
                                                                </a>
                                                            </li>
                                                            <li class="pag_1"><a href="#">1</a></li>
                                                            <li class="pag_2"><a href="#">2</a></li>
                                                            <li class="pag_3 active"><a href="#">3</a></li>

                                                            <li class="disabled">
                                                                <a class="pag_2" href="#" aria-label="Next">
                                                                    <span aria-hidden="true">»</span>
                                                                </a>
                                                            </li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </nav>
                                                </td>

                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   <?php
        require("../fragmentos/es/exit.php");
        require("../fragmentos/es/preferences.php");
    ?>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE 8 se adapte a resolución -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/respond.src.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("select[name=op]").on('change', function () {
                var valor = $(this).val();
                if (valor == "1") {

                    selectDataset(0);
                }
                else if (valor == "2") {

                    selectDataset(2);
                }
                else if (valor == "3") {

                    selectDataset(1);
                }
                else if (valor == "4") {

                    selectDataset(2);
                }
                else {
                    selectDataset(1);
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
    <script>
        $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#myInput').focus()
        })
    </script>
    <script>

        $('#buscar').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#resultados').removeClass("inv");
        })
    </script>
    <script>
        $('.pag_1').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#tabla_2').addClass("inv");
            $('#tabla_1').removeClass("inv");
            $('#tabla_3').addClass("inv");
        })
        $('.pag_2').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#tabla_1').addClass("inv");
            $('#tabla_2').removeClass("inv");
            $('#tabla_3').addClass("inv");
        })
        $('.pag_3').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#tabla_1').addClass("inv");
            $('#tabla_3').removeClass("inv");
            $('#tabla_2').addClass("inv");
        })
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(



    function () {
        $(".al").each(
            function () {
                $(this).attr({
                    "alt": $(this).text(),
                    "title": $(this).text()
                })
            }
        )

    }



)
    </script>
    <script>

        $('.al').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).toggleClass("al");
        })
    </script>
    <!-- Script calendario -->
    <script>
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            autoclose: true
        })

    </script>

    <script>
        $('.input-append.date').datepicker({
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            autoclose: true
        });
    </script>


    <!-- Fin Script calendario -->  
</body>
</html>
```

Excuse me and thanks for your time!

Comment: Use DataTables, that plugin do all the sorting job.

Comment: you may want to include the error message, something a little more informative than "doesn't work"...

Comment: I don't have any error message. Only when I clic in the columns it doesn't do anything...

Comment: And thank you Ulises. I'm going to see if I can do it using DataTables.

Comment: You're loading jQuery twice... "latest" and "1.9.1"

Comment: I can't beleive it Mottie. I'm absolutly stupid so thank you friend. Now it works perfect!

Comment: You're not stupid. That is a very common mistake, and I'm glad you got it working!